# Django - Redirect user to "next" parameter after successful login

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-login

In my code, I am currently using the @login_required decorator. As far as I know (and can see in the URL), this passes to my login view a next parameter holding the original page the user was on. 
After checking the user's credentials, I'm trying to redirect him to the original page, but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm sure this must be really straightforward, but I've been stuck on it for quite some time and I had to ask for help before throwing away my keyboard. 
My view code is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login, authenticate

def login(request):
form_class = LoginForm

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect(?????????)
        else:
            #Error message
return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form_class})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after you check for successful login, you just need to do something like:

```
next_url = request.GET.get('next')
if next_url:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
else:
    return render(request, 'main/main.html')
```

Comment: Finally, it works! I knew it was something stupidly easy to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that you may not want to blindly redirect to any old url that is passed in the querystring. That allows a phishing attacker to basically redirect your users to any domain after login. If that could be a concern, you might want to review how Django's own built in auth package sanitizes the `next_url`. See the `get_redirect_url` function in the [Django Auth source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py).

Comment: I know this answer is nearly one year old, but it's worth noting that the `next` parameter should be valdiated using `is_safe_url` in order to prevent redirecting user to different site.